# Convert reference to map having shared_ptr as value to reference to map having shared_ptr to const as value

Tags: c++

Assume we have a class with a member like
`std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<ObscureType>> member_`
We cannot replace `member` by a map having `std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType>`, because the class has to operate on non-const functions of `ObscureType`.

The class is now supposed to have a function `const std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType>& getUnderlyingMap() const`.
Other classes may have this class as a dependency and have to operate on const functions of `ObscureType`.

We cannot simply write
`return member_` in `getUnderlyingMap()`, as this implicit conversion is not allowed.

Because `static_cast` and `const_cast` do not work, I went with `reinterpret_cast`.

The method body is therefore

```
const std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType>& getUnderlyingMap() const {
    return reinterpret_cast<const std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType>&>(member_);
}
```

Is using `reinterpret_cast` safe in this context?

Are there any better ways to solve this problem? Note that not using `shared_ptr` is not an option because of the way the objects are created (Node-V8 integration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not safe at all.

Two options I can think of: Instead of exposing the map, expose the functionality you need (Less error prone, but also less clean, and you can't use interfaces that require as `std::map`):

```
std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType> getInUnderlyingMap(unsigned int index) const {
    return member_.at(index);  // Might want to return nullptr instead of throwing
}
std::size_t sizeOfUnderlyingMap() const noexcept {
    return member_.size();
}
// etc.
```

Or you can make your `member_` a `std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType>>`, returning it by const reference in `getUnderlyingMap`, and internally using `std::const_pointer_cast` to use it without the const (Ensure that you are assigning non-const pointers though, so `const_pointer_cast` isn't UB):

```
private:
std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType>> member_;

std::shared_ptr<ObscureType> obscure_object(const std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType>& p) noexcept {
    return std::const_pointer_cast<ObscureType>(p);
}
std::shared_ptr<ObscureType> obscure_object(std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType>&& p) noexcept {
    return std::const_pointer_cast<ObscureType>(std::move(p));
}

void internal_method() {
    obscure_object(member_[0]).non_const_method();
}

public:
const std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<const ObscureType>& getUnderlyingMap() const {
    return member_;
}
```

Comment: Second option looks very promising to me!

Answer (score 0):

Reinterpret cast is just as unsafe and implementationd-defined as always, you could just use a C-style cast that would at least stick out to the casual observer. Since it is unlikely that `map<key, value*>` and `map<key, value const*>` have different binary layouts, all that remains is typesafety checks that are pure compile-time mechanisms, so this should work in practice.

Beware this though:

```
int const value = 42;
map<int, int*> m;
map<int, int const*>& m2 = (map<int, int const*>&) m;
// store address of `value`
m2[0] = &value;
// increment constant!
(*m[0]) += 1;
```

Your example gets it right though, you add the const on two levels at once to avoid that modification.